# How do I set an un-selectable default description in a select (drop-down) menu in HTML?

Tags: html, html-select

I have a drop down where the user selects a language:

```
<select>
    <option>English</option>
    <option>Spanish</option>
</select>
```

1. I want the default option that is initially displayed to say "Select
   a language" instead of "English" (my first option, displayed by
   default).
2. I don't want the user to be able to select "Select a language".

Comment: I could be wrong but i think the OP was meant to ask how to show some texts that doesn't belong to the options, like this one: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447134/html-select-how-to-set-default-text-which-wont-be-shown-in-drop-down-list). Both Oded's and Myles's answers are for the situation that you want to show one of the options as the text. And by the way I don't think make it the first option like in Myles's solution is a good design. But this is just my personal opinion.

Comment: @YangChi agree. submitted edit to question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If none of the options in the select have a `selected` attribute, the first option will be the one selected.

In order to select a default option that is not the first, add a `selected` attribute to that option:

```
<option selected="selected">Select a language</option>
```

You can read the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6.1) regarding defaults in select element.

I suggest reading a good HTML book if you need to learn HTML basics like this - I recommend  [Head First HTML](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-HTML-CSS-XHTML/dp/059610197X).

Answer (score 59):

Building on Oded's answer, you could also set the default option but not make it a selectable option if it's just dummy text. For example you could do:

```
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a language</option>
```

This would show "Select a language" before the user clicks the select box but the user wouldn't be able to select it because of the disabled attribute.

Comment: I think it's simpler to take out the `selected="selected"` to just be `selected`. same for `disabled`. Submitted edit. Note that it can be good to include the value if using a parser, from another answer: "What I wrote is valid polyglot HTML/XML. Using <option selected> is okay for a browser, but may cause the document to be rejected by other parsers"

Comment: I love stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

```css
.selectmenu{
  
 -webkit-appearance: none;  /*Removes default chrome and safari style*/
 -moz-appearance: none; /* Removes Default Firefox style*/
 background: #0088cc ;
 width: 200px; /*Width of select dropdown to give space for arrow image*/
 text-indent: 0.01px; /* Removes default arrow from firefox*/
 text-overflow: "";  /*Removes default arrow from firefox*/ /*My custom style for fonts*/
 color: #FFF;
 border-radius: 2px;
 padding: 5px;
    border:0 !important;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(000,000,000, 0.5);
}
.hideoption { display:none; visibility:hidden; height:0; font-size:0; }
```

```html
Try this html

<select class="selectmenu">
<option selected disabled class="hideoption">Select language</option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>
<option>Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make option#1 Select Language:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zJqHm/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Default Text</option>
```

Leaving the disabled flag in prevents them from not selecting an option and the hidden flag will remove it from the list.  In my case I was using it with an enum list as well and the concept holds the same

```
<select asp-for="Property" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<PropertyEnum>()">
                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Property Enum</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: `hidden` doesn't work in all browsers but there's no harm in putting it there if you want some browsers not to show the option. i think in this case it's nice to have the "instruction" while viewing the options.

Answer (score 0):

Put your prompt in the 1st `option` and disable it:

```
<selection>
    <option disabled selected>”Select a language”</option>
    <option>English</option>
    <option>Spanish</option>
</selection>
```

The first option will automatically be the selected default (what you see first when you look at the drop-down) but adding the `selected` attribute is more clear and actually needed when the first field is a disabled field.

The `disabled` attribute will make the option be un-selectable/grayed out.

---

Other answers suggest setting `disabled=“disabled”` but that’s only necessary if you need to parse as XHTML, which is basically a more strict version of HTML. `disabled` on it’s on is enough for standard HTML.

---

I**f you want to make the selection “required”** (without accepting the “Select a language” option as an accepted answer):

Add the `required` attribute to `selection` and set the first `option`’s `value` to the empty string `””`.

```
<selection required>
    <option disabled value=“”>Select a language</option>
    <option>English</option>
    <option>Spanish</option>
</selection>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has an accepted answer but I think this is a much cleaner way to achieve the desired output

```
<select required>
<option value="">Select</option>
<option>English</option>
<option>Spanish</option>
</select>
```

> The **required** attribute in  makes it mandatory to select
>   an option from the list.
>
> **value=""** inside the option tag combined with the **required** attribute in select tag makes selection of '**Select**' option not
>   permissible, thus achieving the required output