# Default text which won't be shown in drop-down list

Tags: html, html-select

I have a `select` which initially shows *Select language* until the user selects a language. When the user opens the select, I don't want it to show a *Select language* option, because it's not an actual option.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 262):

[Kyle's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9447243/282110) worked perfectly fine for me so I made my research in order to avoid any Js and CSS, but just sticking with HTML.
Adding a value of `selected` to the item we want to appear as a header forces it to show in the first place as a placeholder. 
Something like:

```
<option selected disabled>Choose here</option>
```

The complete markup should be along these lines:

```
<select>
    <option selected disabled>Choose here</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

You can take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/Yfs4u/1/), and here's the result:

[image]

If you **do not** want the sort of placeholder text to appear listed in the options once a user clicks on the select box just add the `hidden` attribute like so:

```
<select>
    <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Check the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/pm7cefvg/1/) and the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer but when using Angular  JS, then it doesn't work since Angular automatically adds an empty option and sets it as the default

Comment: Anyway, just for reference, here's how you would do in Angular, just combine the above approach with the Angular specific explained here http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angularjs-adding-user-friendly-ng-options-default

Comment: Note that [the `hidden` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-hidden-attribute), used in the answer above, is an attribute that can be set on any HTML element, and is usually (but not necessarily) implemented to be equivalent to setting `display: none` with CSS.

Comment: Note also that setting `hidden` on an `option` in a `select` doesn't work in Safari, on either iOS or Mac. This answer thus offers only partial browser support.

Comment: Still, this is an attempt at solving the problem at hand using best practices, progressive enhancement and zero hacks. Also, the first option will not be selectable (it's disabled) so the usability on **all platforms** is safeguarded as well

Comment: Is possible can I add color, so that customer can select color instead of text choices like,, colors red, blue color instead of one, two values,,

Answer (score 63):

Here is the solution:

```
<select>
    <option style="display:none;" selected>Select language</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Note that `selected="true"` is invalid. Instead, use `selected="selected"` in (X)HTML or just `selected` in HTML. It seems you confused `selected` attribute with `selected` property, which is changed like this: `myOption.selected = true;` or `myOption.selected = false;`

Comment: "display: none" is ignored by browsers that use device-native selects like Android and iOS. You must remove the option from DOM in select.focus and return it and select it in select.blur to make it work.

Comment: -1; like [Nobita's answer using `hidden`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13492609/1709587) (which is [*"typically implemented in CSS"*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-hidden-attribute) using `display: none` anyway), using `display: none` on an `option` doesn't work in Safari; the option still appears.

Answer (score 55):

The proper and semantic way is using a [placeholder label option](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#placeholder-label-option):

- Add an [`option`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) element as the first child of the [`select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element)
- Set [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-value)`= ""` to that `option`
- Set the placeholder text as the content of that `option`
- Add the [`required`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-select-required) attribute to the `select`

This will force the user to select another option in order to be able to submit the form, and browsers should [render](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-select-element-0) the `option` as desired:

> If a select element contains a placeholder label option, the user
>   agent is expected to render that option in a manner that conveys that
>   it is a label, rather than a valid option of the control.

However, most browsers will render it as a normal `option`. So we will have to do fix it manually, by adding the following to the `option`:

- The [`selected`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-selected) attribute, to make it [selected](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-option-selectedness) by default
- The [`disabled`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-disabled) attribute, to make it non-selectable by the user
- [`display: none`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop), to hide it from the list of values

```css
select > .placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="">Select language</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It should be noted that even this (which is the most thorough attempt at solving this problem out of all the answers here) doesn't work on Safari, either on iOS or Mac. The option will still when the select is opened.

Comment: @MarkAmery I suggest you do like it's proposed in @Nobita answer and simply add the `hidden` attribute to the placeholder option tag instead of `display: none` as it seems that most mobile browsers ignore the `display: none` CSS attribute and it's even more semantically correct in my opinion.

Comment: @Gaboik1 In the comments on that answer, I noted that `hidden` is generally implemented as `display: none` under the hood (and the spec explicitly suggests this as a "typical" implementation). As such, I'd be surprised if there were any browsers - mobile or otherwise - where `hidden` worked but `display: none` did not. Can you provide any example?

Answer (score 22):

Because you can't use assign placeholders for `select` tags, I don't believe that there is any way to do exactly what you're asking for with pure HTML/CSS. You can, however, do something like this:

```
<select>
  <option disabled="disabled">Select language</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

"Select language" will show up in the dropdown, but once another option is selected it will not be possible to reselect it.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I found that the best is the combination of disabled and selected with style="display:none;". disabled is useful when you want to perform validation - it makes sure you have no enabled option selected by default.

Comment: -1 because other answers here (notably Nobtia's and Oriol's) provide both much more explanatory detail and much more complete solutions.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
<div class="selectSelection">
    <select>
        <option>Do not display</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In the CSS:

```
.selectSelection option:first-child{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This answer contains nothing that other answers don't also contain in more detail, plus it has bad formatting; -1.

Answer (score 5):

I have a solution with a span displayed above the select until a selection done. The span displays the default message, and so it's not in the list of propositions:

**HTML:**

```
<span id="default_message_overlay">Default message</span>
<select id="my_select">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>  
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
#default_message_overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    color: grey;
}
select {
    width: 150px;
}
```

**Javascript (with JQuery):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // No selection at start
    $('#my_select').prop("selectedIndex", -1);

    // Set the position of the overlay
    var offset = $('#my_select').offset();
    offset.top += 3;
    offset.left += 3;
    $('#default_message_overlay').offset(offset);

    // Remove the overlay when selection changes
    $('#my_select').change(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("selectedIndex") != -1) {
            $('#default_message_overlay').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I've made a [jsfiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jYA2U/12/). Tested with Firefox and IE8.

Comment: Chrome on OSX always shows the first option selected, but it seems to be OSX specific, because all solutions provided here lead to the first visible option being selected.

Comment: instead of `span` in there use `legend` and that would be perfect or `label`

Comment: This is an interesting approach, and the only possible way that I see of getting this behaviour to work on Safari, but it's badly implemented here; you at least need `pointer-events: none` on your span to allow clicks to pass through to select.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly use this code on the option you do not want it to appear in option list:

```
<option value="" hidden selected>Select Language</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="" id="ddl" name="prop" style="display:none;" disabled selected>chose something </option>
```

you can of course move the css to a css file if you want, and put a script to catch the `esc` button to select the disabled again. Unlike the other similar answers I put `value=""`, this is so if you send the value(s) of your select list with a form, it won't contain "chose something". In asp.net mvc 5 sent as json compiled with `var obj = { prop:$('#ddl').val(),...};` and `JSON.stringify(obj);` the value of prop will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Op1:

```
$("#MySelectid option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() == "text to find") {
            $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
            return;
        }
});
```

Op2:

```
$('#MySelectid option')
.filter(function() { return $.trim( $(this).text() ) == 'text to find'; })​​​​​​​​.attr('selected','selected');​​​​​​​
```