# HTML selection automatically selects first entry

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
  <select #typ class="input" (change)="changeIndex(typ.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let creation of creationComponent>{{creation.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

If I start the application the selection has automatically selected the first option. But I don't want that. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try writing a clause for the attribute selected

Comment: A select has to have a selected option. If you don't explicitly set one using the `selected` attribute the first will be used.

Comment: Add <option value="" selected disabled>Creation...</option>

Comment: @Roy Not disabled...

Comment: Of course I came up with that idea on my own. But I don't really want an empty option tag there if there is another possibility. And the most strange thing is, that the selection has "" as default value if I don't have the (change)-event and the #type.

Comment: @OnLearn The selected answer doesn't work. LoL. https://i.imgur.com/eyNATKd.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a better answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13492609/5039495

We can use `selected`, `disabled` and `hidden` on the default option, this is recognized by safari.

```html
<select>
  <option selected disabled hidden></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

---

*Outdated*

The trick is setting an empty option with `display:none`.

```html
<select>
  <option style="display:none"></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

**Warning**: As reported by other users, this solution doesn't work in Safari and iOS Safari

Comment: Before you get too excited, this doesn't work in Safari or iOS Safari

Comment: @PraveenKumar can you try the newer code on safari?

Comment: @Icycool I don't know if it's intended (doesn't seem so from the code), but this disabled-hidden-selected option can be selected (iOS Safari)

Comment: Does work like it should on the ios 15.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common thing... Just add an empty `<option>` as the first:

```
<select #typ class="input" (change)="changeIndex(typ.value)">
  <option></option>
  <option *ngFor="let creation of creationComponent>{{creation.name}}</option>
</select>
```

You cannot have anything unselected for a `<select>` tag. This should fix it. Quoting from [Turnip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746736/turnip)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816933/html-selection-automatically-selects-first-entry/45816963#comment78591183_45816933): *A select has to have a selected option. If you don't explicitly set one using the selected attribute the first will be used.* For a better version, you can use the following code with `selected` attribute:

```
<select #typ class="input" (change)="changeIndex(typ.value)">
  <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
  <option *ngFor="let creation of creationComponent>{{creation.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Of course I thought about this. But I don't want that it is an option to choose "". If there is any other possibility please let me know, otherwise I have to do that but I knew that solution anyway. But thanks for the answer! And no, not the first one is selected generally. It is only, if there is the #typ and the (change)-event. Otherwise nothing is selected.