# Select input default caption disabled

Tags: html

I have a select input

```
<select>
    <option value="false">OFF</option>
    <option value="true">ON</option>
</select>
```

I want a select input like this (with default caption that cant be selected): [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan no! i want default option can not be selected!

Comment: You added that to your question after I suggested the duplicate. Now I might point you to https://stackoverflow.com/q/9447134/215552

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sorry.i am beginner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the option to `disabled` and `selected`

```
<select>
    <option selected disabled>Auto Play:</option>
    <option value="false">OFF</option>
    <option value="true">ON</option>
</select>
```