# Symfony how to disable the default option

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

According to this URL [Set Default Text in a Select (drop-down) box/menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212939/set-default-text-in-a-select-drop-down-box-menu) I need add `disabled` attribute for the placeholder in symfony. This is my code.

```
$builder
    ->add('name', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Business Name',
    ))           
    ->add('country', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Country',
        'property' => 'name',
        'placeholder' => 'Please select',
    ));
```

Now I need to add `disabled` like `<option value="" disabled>Please select</option>`

How can I do it? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Think about it: having a "Please select" option that is disabled, means that item (country 1) would be the thing selected instead. So it wouldn't be much of a placeholder.

Comment: Have you resolve your issue since 3 month ? I would like to know the answer...

Answer (score 2):

if this topic is still open... I had a similar problem today and managed it this way. (tested in symfony 2.7.10)

Obviously the `placeholder` is a standalone attribute in vars, therefore you cannot select it in the `finishView`.

In your `buildForm` method:

```
$builder->add('label', 'choice', array(
    'data' => $var, // your default data
    'read_only' => true,
    'placeholder' => false, // implement a condition to check wether you want the choice read only
));
```

Implement the `finishView` Method (Interface implementation from `AbstractType`):

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    foreach ($view->children['country']->vars['choices'] as $id => $choiceView) {
        // implement a condition to prevent the accepted/wanted option be disabled
        if ($id != $yourAcceptedValueId) {
            $choiceView->attr = ['disabled' => 'disabled'];
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately in the choices list is no placeholder option, so you have to implement two settings to achieve this.

Greets

Answer (score 2):

It's way easier to do it like this :

```
$builder->add('civility', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => [
        'Civility*' => '',
        'Mrs.' => 1,
        'Mr.' => 2,
    ],
    'required' => 'required',
    'choice_attr' => ['Civility*' => ['disabled'=>'']]
])
```

So when the form loads you'll get : `<option value disabled selected="selected">Civility*</option>`

Then you can add some css `option[disabled] {color: #9f9f9f;}`

Comment: This still works perfectly with Symfony5. One hint: For MacOS you also need to add `select:invalid { color: #9f9f9f; }` to style it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* ... */
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class YourBusinessFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($view->children['country']->children as $country) {
            if ($country->vars['value'] == "") {
                $country->vars['attr']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
            }
        }
    }
/* ... */
```

Comment: how finishView method is trigger? this code is not working form me.

Comment: where you put this method?

Comment: I assume, that You have your own FormType like RegistrationType or something, your type is extended by Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType and there is finishView.

Comment: Testing this example just for fun, it looks like the ['country']->children is empty `[]` at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

*Why add an disabled option when you can set a value for empty value ?*

```
$builder->add('states', 'entity', array(
    'empty_value' => 'Choisissez une option',
));
```

Comment: `empty_value` is the value that should be used on the server if the user submitted the form without selecting an option. This is different from forcing the user to select an option before submitting the form so the default option is never valid.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#placeholder), set the `placeholder` parameter to `false` to disable/avoid the default option:

```
$builder
    ->add('name', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Business Name',
    ))           
    ->add('country', 'entity', array(
        'class'       => 'AppBundle:Country',
        'property'    => 'name',
        'placeholder' => false,
    ));
```

---

Prior to Symfony2.6, you can use the `empty_value` parameter instead:

```
$builder
    ->add('name', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Business Name',
    ))           
    ->add('country', 'entity', array(
        'class'       => 'AppBundle:Country',
        'property'    => 'name',
        'empty_value' => false,
    ));
```

Comment: placeholder value is showing in correctly in my form view. I just need disabled it.

Comment: Then dawid's answer should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own form type and create a template for this form type. For example: you create form type with name `CountrySelectorType` and set parent `EntityType` or `ChoiceType`. Next you need to create a folder and file `form_types/fields.html.twig` (or any other name) in your `app/Resources/views` folder and add this path to your config.yml file, for ex:

```
twig:
  debug: '%kernel.debug%'
  strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
  form_themes:
      - 'form/fields.html.twig'
```

And [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) you can find all filed layouts for your custom field type

Next you just copy a parent widget code to your fields.html.twig file, change widget name according to your type field name and customize it like you want. I also has the same problem so my custom city selector type with disabled default option looks like below:

```
{% block country_selector_widget %}
    {%- if required and placeholder is none and not placeholder_in_choices and not multiple and (attr.size is not defined or attr.size <= 1) -%}
        {% set required = false %}
    {%- endif -%}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %} class="form-control">
        {%- if placeholder is not none -%}
            <option {% if is_filer_form_field %}disabled{% endif %} value=""{% if required and value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ placeholder != '' ? (translation_domain is same as(false) ? placeholder : placeholder|trans({}, translation_domain)) }}
            </option>
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- if preferred_choices|length > 0 -%}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            {%- if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none -%}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- set options = choices -%}
        {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
    </select>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -2):

It should look like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('name', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Business Name',
    ))           
    ->add('country', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Country',
        'property' => 'name',
        'placeholder' => 'Please select',
        'attr' => array('disabled'=>'disabled')
    ));
```

Here is documentation for this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#attr

Comment: no i need not disable the dropdown. i need disable the empty option.